# Do conditional checks cause bottlenecks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I do a lot of Javascript programming that checks for the presence of something (library, window, socket) before executing code.

```
if (foo()) {
  do this thing
}
```

Sometimes `foo()` gets set only once, but then I will check it over and over again during execution.  React's `useRef()` is an good example.

```
const setRef = useRef(null)

setSomeRef = (someCondition)

if (someRef.current) { // someRef is defined and available
  // repeatedly execute some function 
}
```

My question: is repeatedly checking for the same, unchanging variable to be set during repeated execution a bottleneck?  Can it be avoided?  In the particular case of JavaScript, does memorization or some similar process make the check faster?

I get that this is a common thing to do (`while(true)` being example #1) but I'm interested in 1) the effect of these checks on program efficiency -- especially as relates to JavaScript and 2) alternative approaches.

Comment: How could you do that any differently?  If you need to check a condition, then you need to check a condition.  What makes you think it has any measurable impact on performance?  It's almost certainly swamped by whatever processing is going on inside the conditional.

Comment: I think this depends on how you define "bottleneck". Repeatedly checking the same condition knowing it has not changed is definitely inefficient. But if you need to check the condition, then what else can you do? If the condition is just evaluating some value stored in memory, the impact on performance will be negligible.

Comment: What counts as "repeated execution" here? If it's inside a tight loop that's running a million times, sure it counts toward the bottleneck. If it's inside a react component that's rendered just once, it won't make a difference. If it's inside a react component that's re-rendered a lot, it's still not a bottleneck; and you'd have to choose a different framework than react to be able to optimise this.

Comment: I don't know how you could do it any differently, and maybe you can't!  I think I see it as branching into code that never checks the state again but executes the code until the state changes.  But that's really just a re-explanation of the original problem, isn't it?  @Bergi I'm talking about a react component that might be rendered over and over and over again.  A drawing program or game, for instance.  I don't mean to focus on React specifically though.  This could be true in any language.

Comment: @Raydot One check per render is nothing. It won't be a bottleneck. Sure, it's slightly inefficient, but really hard to optimise - you'd probably have to change the entire architecture to call different functions (for different states) in the first place. No, you won't be able to "memorize" this (you're thinking of react's `useMemo`, right?), looking for the memoized value is at least as costly as just doing the check directly. And probably both are nothing compared to the "do this thing" code that'll run every time.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks.  I get it's "nothing compared to."  That's absolutely true.  I'm wondering if useMemo somehow "chunks" the response so that it operates at a lower level, but maybe the browser already accounts for this.

Comment: No, `useMemo` operates at a much higher level. It creates the dependency array, then does function call, then accesses some state/ref from the current component that react keeps around (similar to `useRef`), then does lots of comparisons between the new dependency value and the stored dependency value, then with the result of that comparison it does a conditional call of yet another function, etc... There is no special treatment by the browser for any of this. It's just executing standard JavaScript code (from a library called "react", in this case). Try stepping through it with a debugger!

Comment: "Try stepping through it with a debugger!"  Excellent idea, although I can just imagine what will happen without doing it, and of course you're right.  Maybe I can run some speed checks on different logic setups, and that will provide me with my answer.  @Bergi, if you want to try to shape all of the above into an answer, I'm glad to award you the points.